# Can you use a COUNT() with a WHERE clause within a multi column SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add the result of a filtered COUNT() to a multi column SELECT as such:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AuditTable(
      PlaceId,
      Latitude,
      Longitude,
      IsOpen,
      EventCount
    )
      SELECT
        PlaceId,
        Latitude,
        Longitude,
        IsOpen,
        EvCount
      FROM (UPDATE P
              SET
                IsOpen = OpenTimeCalc.IsOpen

            OUTPUT
              INSERTED.PlaceId,
              INSERTED.Location,
              INSERTED.Latitude,
              INSERTED.Longitude,
              INSERTED.IsOpen,
              (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM E
               WHERE Event.Date >= LT.LocalDateTime
               AND E.PlaceId = P.PlaceId) AS EvCount

           FROM Place AS P
           JOIN Timezone AS TZ
             ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
           JOIN Event AS E
             ON P.PlaceId = Event.PlaceId

           CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT
               GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE TZ.Name AS LocalDateTime
           ) AS LT
     )
```

I'm using a nested DML.

But it doesn't seem to work and I can't find an example like this one online.

Is it possible?

I tried to look for an answer online because I tried to add the `SELECT` keyword before the `COUNT()`, to create a `CROSS APPLY` and to call it afterwards but nothing seems to work.

Comment: *it doesn't seem to work* - this is not helpful. you are, however, missing a `select` in your subquery.

Comment: This doesn't seem right - you should probably use a window function to get the "EvCount" for each row. Also it would be good if you posted an sql fiddle otherwise it's very difficult to answer authoritatively.

Comment: you can have a subquery returning a single value as a column expression. If you say it doesn't work, you need to show us a more complete query you tried, and the error message or sample input and expected vs received output .

Comment: If you you want to count rows for a given criteria, use GROUP BY. The way you have it. even if it works, will show 1 for all rows.

Comment: I see, sorry for the lack of details, I thought there was a way to do it that I didn't know. @tinazmu do you mean like a scalar subquery ?

Comment: yes, like a scalar subquery; isn't it what you want to do?

Comment: @tinazmu yes that's what I tried to do, let me try some code and I'll post an update with a test

Comment: Please show the rest of your query. It looks like you might need a subquery or a window function, but hard to say.

Comment: I've updated my question with the rest of my query

Comment: You're right I've added the references to LT and the joins

Comment: Well you can use a window function in a derived subquery or CTE, then update that directly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c01cb7/24

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface, I created this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/djZE4717) to make it easier to test with test data and it's working, you're awesome man I didn't read the OVER part of my TSQL book because I thought it was too advanced but I'm going to right now to understand your code better. Thank you ! - Also, I didn't know you could add any column you wanted to an OUTPUT statement, I thought was only the INSERTED or the DELETED columns

Comment: It gets a bit tricky: `INSERT` only allows the `inserted` table, and `UPDATE` `DELETE` `MERGE` allow any table, but you cannot use a column in the CTE being modified if that column is a calculated column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use a window function over one of the tables before you join it, the put that into the `OUTPUT` clause.

```sql
UPDATE P
SET
  IsOpen = 1

OUTPUT
  inserted.PlaceId,
  inserted.Latitude,
  inserted.Longitude,
  inserted.IsOpen,
  ISNULL(E.EvCount, 0)
INTO dbo.AuditTable(
  PlaceId,
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  IsOpen,
  EventCount
)

FROM Place AS P
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT E.*,
      EvCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN E.Date >= LT.LocalDateTime THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY E.PlaceId)
    FROM Event AS E
    JOIN Timezone AS TZ
      ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
    CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
        GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE TZ.Name AS LocalDateTime
    ) AS LT
    WHERE P.PlaceId = E.PlaceId
) AS E;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c01cb7/24)

To be honest, looking at the logic it seems you don't even need a window function, you can use regular aggregation.

```sql
UPDATE P
SET
  IsOpen = 1

OUTPUT
  inserted.PlaceId,
  inserted.Latitude,
  inserted.Longitude,
  inserted.IsOpen,
  ISNULL(E.EvCount, 0)
INTO dbo.AuditTable(
  PlaceId,
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  IsOpen,
  EventCount
)

FROM Place AS P
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      EvCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN E.Date >= LT.LocalDateTime THEN 1 END)
    FROM Event AS E
    JOIN Timezone AS TZ
      ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
    CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
        GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE TZ.Name AS LocalDateTime
    ) AS LT
    WHERE P.PlaceId = E.PlaceId
) AS E;
```

Comment: Charlie your answer is right but the JOIN Timezone part doesn't work and returns this error "The multi-part identifier "P.TimezoneId" could not be bound.", do you know why it doesn't ? Besides that it works.

Comment: This is excellent. It works like a charm. However there's a case where it doesn't output the places if they have no event, so I just replaced your `CROSS APPLY` with an `OUTER APPLY` and it outputs them with a `null` value. Would you know how to make it put a '0' instead of `null` ? I tried to add `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in the `CASE WHEN` but it kind of breaks the statement.

Comment: `ISNULL(E.EvCount, 0)` in the `OUTPUT` section. But see edit.

Comment: This is a great idea. Thank you, it works in the main `SELECT` part but not in the `OUTPUT`. It this fine ? Or could it create issues later the fact that it isn't in the `OUTPUT` section ?

Comment: I thought that if it wasn't in the `OUTPUT` clause like you said, it being the actual data being selected by the `SELECT`, it could run into a bug somehow. Because the `ISNULL` doesn't work on the `OUTPUT` and I was trying to reproduce it the way you said to do it but it seems to be working the same as if it were in the `OUTPUT` clause .

Comment: Works fine here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c01cb7/29 not sure what you mean about a `SELECT` there isn't one in that code, only an `UPDATE`

Comment: Oh sorry I was referring to my own code, I thought I shared it but I'm using your code within a stored procedure using that `UPDATE` within a nested DML so there's a `SELECT` that selects the result of the `OUTPUT` and inserts it into a table.

Answer (score 0):

Initially sub-query is executed inside curly braces. I think your sub-query is wrong. `Count(*)` is wrong. Because SQL Server does not know which columns get counts. This is my guess code. Maybe this is not work. But the structure should like this.

```
SELECT
    [PlaceId],
    [Latitude],
    [Longitude],
    [IsOpen],
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [E]
        WHERE [Event].[Date] >= [LT].[LocalDateTime]
        AND [E].[PlaceId] = [LT].[PlaceId]
    ) AS [EvCount]
FROM [LT]
```